# How Superuser Users profiles are being sorted?

Tags: support, user-profiles, users

In which basis user profiles are displayed(in Users tab)? For sure they are not random. And there is a number(may indicate some score) under user's name. What is that?

Comment: You mean by default of the reputation they have earned this month? Or something else?

Comment: @random-I'm asking that only. I have just visited the Users tab. Seen my profile in the first page itself. And it has a value 347. Don't know what does it indicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In case the image isn't clear, there are different tabs to display the criteria which the users are sorted. Stack Exchange tends to explain a lot via tool tips, so hover your mouse over the tabs and numbers and you'll know what is what.

[image]

---

[image]